# Spring Cache Abstraction + EhCache

Tags: spring, java

Добрый вечер. В веб-приложении для кэширования используется связка Spring Cache Abstraction + EhCache.
Кэширую метод DAO-уровня:

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value="cityCache", key="#root.methodName")
public List<City> getActiveMainCities(){

 Session sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
 List<City> cities = (List<City>)sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM city WHERE cit_enable IS TRUE").addEntity(City.class).list();

 return cities; 
}
```

Метод Service-уровня выглядит так:

```
@Override
public List<City> getActiveMainCities(){

 return cityDao.getActiveMainCities();
}
```

Далее, это метод вызывается в контроллере:

```
List<City> cities = cityService.getActiveMainCities();
```

И тут начинается самое интересное! Если в контроллере сделать так:

```
List<City> cities = cityService.getActiveMainCities();
cities.add(new City("London", true));
```

то закэшируется модифицированный список , т.е. содержащий город London, а не то, что было на выходе метода DAO-уровня.

Почему? Может быть, так и должно быть? Пожалуйста, если кто знает, почему так происходит, поделитесь знаниями. )

Answer (score 1):

Кэшируется результат вызова вашего метода. Вы возвращаете модифицируемый список. Поведение соответствует ожидаемому.

Просто возвращайте immutable список. Элементы списка конечно тоже должны быть immutable. Иначе вы рискуете модифицировать закэшированное значение.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, если изменить значение из EhCache - оно поменяется и прямо в кэше, что порой неудобно... либо используйте внешнюю реализацию кэша (memcache/redis), либо не меняйте полученные объекты, либо используйте immutable объекты&коллекции, либо оберните все вызовы @Cacheable копирующими фукнциями.